# How many NSOperationQueues is too many?

Tags: performance, cocoa, nsoperationqueue

Is it a good practice to have multiple `NSOperationQueue`s?  I currently am writing an application that has a `NSOperationQueue` that kicks off multiple `NSOperation`s.  Each operation then starts its own queue and executes its own separate `NSOperation`s.  I don't have any issues with this model so far and everything is operating as it is supposed to (I'm not experiencing any deadlock).

Is that considered a good practice?  Is there a point where you have too many `NSOperationQueue`s?

Comment: Yes you can create multiple NSOperationQueues in application. But my suggestion use one one NSOperationQueues and add NSOperations using dependency.

Comment: Depending on the NSOperation tasks your can also use a single NSOperationQueue and set the the maxConcurrentOperationCount property to allow or not concurency executions or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best is use GCD global queues IMO ;) the OS knows how many queues is best :D
But You can have multiple queues.. the OS won't break if you use some

But seriously:

How many highly depends not only on the OS also on what they would be doing! (CPU only, IO? ...)

### there is no real exact number.

Use what you need, feel comfortable with and **what makes sense semantically(!)**

Comment: `NSOperationQueue` is built on top of libdispatch.

Comment: nowadays yes. but an operation queue must use that at all. BUT i edited the answer

Comment: I think I'm going to use a global NSOperationQueue in my App Delegate and then just add the operations from anywhere I need operations performed.